# Buzzing from doorbell transformer?

Tags: transformer, doorbell

I have a Nest Wired Doorbell (gen 2). The transformer that was already in my house was not powerful enough to drive the doorbell, so I replaced it with a [transformer](https://www.homedepot.com/p/309792479) I found at Home Depot.

This was half a year ago. The doorbell and transformer worked fine, although the chime would buzz when someone rang the doorbell as shown in this [video](https://imgur.com/Qk3sVpT).

However, this week I replaced some switches around my house that were on the same circuit as the doorbell transformer. All those switches are wired correctly, but since doing so the doorbell transformer now has a constant buzz ([video](https://imgur.com/2dhtwCx)).

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The switch replacement is not related. Presumably when you did it, you ended up toggling the power to the transformer, which changed the resting state of it to emphasize an existing buzz. You might try toggling the power to the transformer again to see if it changes the sound for the better. Ultimately I strongly suspect you will need to replace the transformer to eliminate the buzz. You can validate that by disconnecting the output wires. If the buzz continues, it's replacement time for sure. If the buzz stops, it's possible that something connected to the output is now shorted or otherwise drawing way too much power, and that's the cause of the buzz.